# strange output number ( C )

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    int h;
    int m;
    scanf_s("%d : %d", &h,&m);
    printf("%d : %d", h,m);

    return 0;
}
```

That is it,
I typed 12 13
It gave me 12 : -858993460

ironic.. would you give me an idea?

Comment: This is totally irrelevant, but I don't think you're using "ironic" correctly. Much more relevantly, please use the appropriate language tags.

Comment: Is `12 13` your input via the console?  Your `scanf()` function is expecting the format `12 : 13` with spaces and colon included (but excluding quotation marks).

Answer (score 4):

If you typed exactly "12 13" as you wrote in the question, then the issue is that your input does not match the format specified in your call to `scanf`. In particular, `scanf` is only looking for input in the form of `<some integer> : <some integer>`. Note that your input does NOT include the `:` character. As such, `scanf` only successfully reads a number into your first variable (`h`), but fails to read into the second variable (`m`).

You can confirm this is the case by checking the return value of `scanf`, which returns "the number of input items successfully matched" (see [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)).

The reason you're seeing a "random" number in the output is that your variable `m` is never initialized. If you instead initialize it to `0`, then you will no longer see a "random" value. This is good practice anyway.

For example (with error check):

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    int h = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int rc = scanf_s("%d : %d", &h,&m);
    if (rc != 2) { // expect to read 2 values
        printf("scanf failed, read %d value(s)\n", rc);
    } else {
        printf("%d : %d", h,m);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the format in `scanf_s("%d : %d", &h,&m);`

`scanf()`:
The C library function `int scanf(const char *format, ...)` reads formatted input from stdin.

In your case, type 12 : 13

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the `scanf_s` function expects a colon in the input, but you didn't type one, so nothing got stored in `m` in the call. As a result, you got a garbage value for `m` (as you didn't initialize it either). If you type in `12 : 13`, then you should get the expected result.

Also, make sure to check the return value of `scanf_s` to make sure that you've got all of the values you want.